# How to store data in struct member which is also a pointer?

Tags: c

**This is the struct that I have to use**

```
struct subject {  
char subjectID[10];  
float marks; }; 

struct student {  
char name[20];  
char ID[10];  
struct subject *enrolled; };
```

**My program has to let the students enroll in more than one subject, how do I store this???**

Comment: I would say as a dynamically managed array (which means you probably want to add a fourth member; `enrolled_count`, telling you how many `struct subject`s the `enrolled` member points to).

Comment: You should code between braces `{}` to make your code more readable, especially when your programs increase in length. You can create an array of structs for courses that the student is enrolled in.

Comment: Is it really true that you have to use those **exact** struct definitions? They don't seem sufficient for maintaining a list of enrolled subjects per student.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding 2 elements to your structure `student`.
Add a dynamic array of `subject` and a `enrolled_count` and using that track enrolled subjects.
An example:

```
struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    char ID  [10];
    struct subject *enrolled;
    int enrolled_count;
}
```

So when you access it somewhere you can use Student.enrolled[index] (the . can be -> depends if it's a pointer to a struct)

Comment: Credit : @WhozCraig as he mentioned the count of elements in the comments.